# How to break the rank of a variable into decimals according to the rank of a second variable in R, in order to break ties

Tags: r, excel, break, rank

How, in R, break ties from V1 according to the rank of V2, using the excel rank-based method, as described on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fD5vhb36j0

More precisely, the question is not ordering, but rather to adjust the rank of V1 (by '*adjust*', I mean '*split into decimals*') according to that of V2, in order to adjust integer ties from V1 to the ascending rank of V2.

Let assume these initial data, given as example:

```
dat0 <- data.frame(V1=c(18,20,21,22,22,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,27),
V2=c(13,54,3,7,23,10,13,24,25,5,9,16,6,8,11,13,18,9,10,9))
```

The goal to reach is:

```
> dat0
   V1 V2 rank_V1 tiebreak rank_V1_adjusted V1_adjusted
1  18 13       1     0.00             1.00       18.00
2  20 54       2     0.00             2.00       20.00
3  21  3       3     0.00             3.00       21.00
4  22  7       4     0.20             4.20       22.20
5  22 23       4     0.85             4.85       22.85
6  23 10       6     0.45             6.45       23.45
7  23 13       6     0.60             6.60       23.60
8  23 24       6     0.90             6.90       23.90
9  23 25       6     0.95             6.95       23.95
10 24  5      10     0.10            10.10       24.10
11 24  9      10     0.30            10.30       24.30
12 24 16      10     0.75            10.75       24.75
13 25  6      13     0.15            13.15       25.15
14 25  8      13     0.25            13.25       25.25
15 25 11      13     0.55            13.55       25.55
16 25 13      13     0.60            13.60       25.60
17 25 18      13     0.80            13.80       25.80
18 26  9      18     0.30            18.30       26.30
19 26 10      18     0.45            18.45       26.45
20 27  9      20     0.00            20.00       27.00
```

The excel formulaes based on the youtube tutos are:

```
V1 (column A): Vector V1
V2 (column B): vector V2
rank_V1 (column C): =RANG(A2;$A$2:$A$21;1)  
tiebreak (column D): =SI(NB.SI($C$2:$C$21;C2)>1;RANG(B2;$B$2:$B$21;1)/NB(B:B);0)  
rank_V1_adjusted (column E): =C2+D2  
V1_adjusted (column F): =SI(D2<>0;A2+D2;A2)
```

Whatever the way, a function that would do this would be really useful.
Thanks for your help

Comment: If you take a look at `help("order")`, you'll see you can order by multiple variables, and "In the case of ties in the first vector, values in the second are used to break the ties."

Comment: Thank you duckmayr. The 'help(order)' does not respond to the problem, neither does this link. The question is rather how to translate the 'tiebreak' excel function into a R function so that the adjusted ranks have decimals.

Comment: @demon My apologies, I thought the goal was as the title said, to break ties according to a second variable. I didn't realize the `tiebreak` decimal column was an actual target of interest; I thought it was just secondary to getting the proper ordering of the data frame.

Comment: @demon maybe you can change the title of your question to make it clear that you are not interested in the ordering but in the construction of `tiebreak`.
Also, could you explain the logic behind `tiebreak`: I have never fond of Excel formulas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward if you know dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

dat0 <- data.frame(V1=c(18,20,21,22,22,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,27),
                   V2=c(13,54,3,7,23,10,13,24,25,5,9,16,6,8,11,13,18,9,10,9))

dat0 <- dat0 %>%
  arrange(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(rank_V1 = rank(V1, ties="min"),
         tiebreak = rank(V2, ties="min")/n()) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(tiebreak = case_when(n() == 1 ~ 0, T ~ tiebreak)) %>%
  mutate(rank_V1_adjusted = rank_V1 + tiebreak,
         V1_adjusted = V1 + tiebreak) %>%
  as.data.frame
         

   V1 V2 rank_V1 tiebreak rank_V1_adjusted V1_adjusted
1  18 13       1     0.00             1.00       18.00
2  20 54       2     0.00             2.00       20.00
3  21  3       3     0.00             3.00       21.00
4  22  7       4     0.20             4.20       22.20
5  22 23       4     0.85             4.85       22.85
6  23 10       6     0.45             6.45       23.45
7  23 13       6     0.60             6.60       23.60
8  23 24       6     0.90             6.90       23.90
9  23 25       6     0.95             6.95       23.95
10 24  5      10     0.10            10.10       24.10
11 24  9      10     0.30            10.30       24.30
12 24 16      10     0.75            10.75       24.75
13 25  6      13     0.15            13.15       25.15
14 25  8      13     0.25            13.25       25.25
15 25 11      13     0.55            13.55       25.55
16 25 13      13     0.60            13.60       25.60
17 25 18      13     0.80            13.80       25.80
18 26  9      18     0.30            18.30       26.30
19 26 10      18     0.45            18.45       26.45
20 27  9      20     0.00            20.00       27.00
```

Comment: There is a `min_rank` in `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you so much @thc, your code works perfectly! Don't know if this could be turned into a function, e.g. 'breakties(data, V1, V2)' coded so that only the last column (V1_adjusted) is added to the dataframe, but your code is already very useful.